# Как вывести на печать что-то с большим количеством перменных?

Tags: python, python-3.x, print

этот код:

`print(translated + " b = " + b + " x = " + x)`

выводит ошибку...

Как мне её решить?

Comment: замените `+`   на `,`

Comment: спасибо большое, ломал голову что не так пол часа)

Answer (score 3):

Форматируйте строку:

```
print(f"{translated} b = {b} x = {x}")
```

Answer (score 2):

В Питоне 3.8+ возможно это сделать так:

```
print(f"{translated} {b = } {x = }")
```

`=` за именем переменной в фигурных скобках значит, что будет выводиться *не только значение переменной,* но тоже *ее имя* (и знак `=` ).

---

Тест:

```
In[2]: translated, b, x = "переводный", 7, "что-то"

In[3]: print(f"{translated} {b = } {x = }")
```

> ```
> переводный b = 7 x = 'что-то'
> ```

```
In[4]: print(f"{translated} {b=} {x=}")       # без пробелов перед / за символом =
```

> ```
> переводный b=7 x='что-то'
> ```